# Question about some algebra theorem

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, self-learning

1.

[image]

order-presserving = monotonic

But we haven't define order structure on the ring.

2.

[image]

I try to prove x is a unit <=> (x)=A ,and fail.

That's what I think:

=>

we want to prove (x)=A.

(x)=A mean Ax=A, so we need to prove f:a->ax is bijective

bijective=injective+surjective

surjective: For every ax,there exist a such that f(a)=ax

injective: failed

presume I succeed in proving it

then |A|=|Ax|

hence A=Ax

<=

I have no idel to prove it.

:(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose we talk about *commutative* rings.

1. The order is on the set of *ideals* of the ring (by inclusion) and not on the ring itself.
2. Very good thoughts. Well, actually, in this context $Ax$ denotes the set $\{ax\,\mid\,a\in A\}$, and once you showed surjectivity of $a\mapsto ax$, you are done, as it already proves that this set $Ax$ contains all elements of $A$ (and of course, it cannot contain more).
   However, if $x$ is a unit, it means it has a multiplicative inverse $x^{-1}$, and then $a\mapsto ax^{-1}$ is *inverse* of $a\mapsto ax$, so it is also *injective*:
   $$ax=bx \ \implies a=axx^{-1}=bxx^{-1}=b\,.$$

For the other direction, assume that $Ax=A=(1)$, in particular $1\in Ax$, i.e. $1=ax$ for some $x$, that is, $x\,|\,1$, $\ x\,$ is a unit.

Comment: 1.we haven't define oreder structure on ideal too.2.thanks,but we haven't use "x is a unit".

Comment: You used it when you showed surjectivity of $a\mapsto ax$. And I used it by the existence of $x^{-1}$. (Surjectivity also easily follows: for any $a\in A$, we have $(ax^{-1})\cdot x\ =\ a$).

Comment: what exactly is the order's mean,@rschwieb said it's a partial order,but what 's the mean of a≥b.a-b∈I?

Comment: The partial order is on the set of *ideals* of the ring and not on the ring itself. An ideal $I$ is less than or equal to an ideal $J$ iff $I\subseteq J$.

Answer (score 2):

1. The order in question is the *partial order by containment on the ideals of the ring*, but not on the elements of the ring. This partial order on the ideals always exists.
2. Now for the second question:

> *presume I succeed in proving it. then |A|=|Ax| hence $A=Ax$*

Well, for finite rings that would be true, but there is no reason why $|A|=|Ax|$ should imply that $A=Ax$ in general. This is all a bit beside the point anyway. You don't need to worry about bijectivity of this map. It's simpler than that.

Let's start again. Of course, we always shave that $Ax\subseteq A$. The main problem is to show the other containment, that $A\subseteq Ax$. If $x$ is a unit, then look at $(Ax^{-1})x\subseteq Ax$. If instead you assume that $A\subseteq Ax$, then consider that $1\in Ax$, and go from there.

The thing to take away is that as soon as an ideal contains a unit, it becomes the whole ring. (The converse is obvious for rings with identity.)

Your original strategy of trying to show $a\mapsto ax$ is *onto* $A$ is actually a valid path, but I just wanted to mention this direct approach too.

Comment: partial oreder is a relation,this relation is the binary operation? Additive or mutiplicative?

Comment: You are right,I ignored the infinite,the poor kid,always ignored by me.lol

Comment: @program666 The order on the ideals is $\subseteq$. That is, $A\leq B$ means that the set $A$ is included in the set $B$.